# Android Studio: Send text as a "textbox"

Tags: java, android, text, android-edittext

I am trying to do an application with a "feed" kind of method, where you type your message and the text message would appear on the top of the screen.
Just like a messenger application, it sends the text but without database.
This is a local application without internet connection.

So I just want to pop up "EditText"'s message to the top of the view, and whenever I write another message, the uppest message would go down by "1 step" and the newest message would be at top.

I know that there might be tutorial for this / been asked before, but I do not really know how to find it by name, because my google results only return me a method to message a real text message by some SMS method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I decided to not use Pusher, because all I wanted was TextView that prints to layout, then whenever another textview is created, it will be on another position. Here is the script for it:

```
public void sendMessage(View v) {

    EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String feedMsg = mEdit.getText().toString();
    if (feedMsg.equals("")) {
        // Do not send the message
    } else {
        View linLayout = findViewById(R.id.linLayout);

        TextView newMsg = new TextView(this);

        newMsg.setText("Player just created a group called " + feedMsg + "!\n" + getDate());
        newMsg.setId(5);
        newMsg.setTextSize(20);
        newMsg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F655F080"));
        newMsg.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        newMsg.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        ((LinearLayout) linLayout).addView(newMsg);
        mEdit.setText(""); // Clears the text
        hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this); // Hides the keyboard

        Toast msgToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        msgToast.show(); // Shows the notification about the successful message
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help anyways, I will use pusher for the future projects!

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this library: [pusher](https://blog.pusher.com/build-an-android-chat-app-with-pusher/)

I think it's just what you need, plus there are some examples in the documentation

Comment: If it helped please upvote and marked as answered. If not write a feedback so that I would know what else is needed. :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried to add the dependencies and synchronize the project, but this error will pop up:                              
Error:(32, 0) startup failed:
build file '\app\build.gradle': 32: expecting '}', found ',' @ line 32, column 65.
   roid:android-async-http:1.4.9', // for o
                                 ^

Comment: EDIT: Fixed it by adding a semicolon instead of a comma. Strange, but will inform after I've done

Comment: Great, glad I could help. It would be nice if you marked as answered with the tick.